# Ruby module inheritance

Tags: ruby

I want to encapsulate a few modules under one module to get the "Liskov substitution principle" in my app.

I'm using the wisper gem for my pub sub logic, and trying to make a generic sub class for all subscribers. the subscribers in my case are stateless and therefore implemented as singleton.

I want them all to include a module this module should "inherit" Singletone module and Wisper::Publisher module.

Is it possible? how?

I tried the basics,

```
module PubSubBase
  include Wisper::Publisher
  include Singleton

 def self.included(base)
   base.extend(Wisper::Publisher::ClassMethods)
 end

end
```

Comment: What happened when you tried this?

Comment: some methods were missing and I got exceptions..

Comment: Could you add some detail and examples?